# Is the facebook php sdk 3.2.3 still useable?

Tags: facebook, facebook-php-sdk

Is the facebook php sdk 3.2.3 still useable? Because it seems like the very basic examples are not working anymore.

I've tried to look for an official statement, but could not find one.

I'm using the example from: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/php/gettingstarted/3.2.3

I've seen the note at the top, that says:

> This document refers to an outdated version of PHP SDK. Please use the latest version.

...but "please use" sounds not like you have to...right?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can still use it - after all it uses CURL calls like the PHP SDK 4. Although it is recommended to use the latest SDK. My personal opinion is that you should not use any PHP SDK at all for smaller projects. User the JS SDK for authorization and API calls and custom PHP CURL calls for stuff that needs to happen on the server.

Bonus: You don´t need PHP5.4+ for your own CURL calls.